# How to resolve this problems with move semantics

Tags: c++

Here is my sample code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
struct Message {
public:
    T data;

    Message(const T& data) {
        this->data = data;
    };

    Message(T&& data) {
        this->data = std::move(data);
    }
};

template <typename T>
class Store {
public:
    Store() {
        segment_ = nullptr;
    }

    void Add(const T& d) {
        segment_ = new Message<T>(d);
    }

    void Add(T&& d) {
        segment_ = new Message<T>(d);
    }
private:
    Message<T>* segment_;
};

struct MoveOnlyExample {
    MoveOnlyExample() = delete;
    explicit MoveOnlyExample(int) {}
    MoveOnlyExample(MoveOnlyExample&&) = default;
    MoveOnlyExample(const MoveOnlyExample&) = delete;
    ~MoveOnlyExample() {}
    MoveOnlyExample& operator=(MoveOnlyExample&&) = default;
    MoveOnlyExample& operator=(const MoveOnlyExample&) = delete;
};

int main() {
    Store<int> int_store;
    int_store.Add(1);

    Store<MoveOnlyExample> store;
    MoveOnlyExample m{1};
    store.Add(std::move(m));
    return 0;
}
```

I have two errors:

```
main.cpp:8:5: error: call to deleted constructor of 'MoveOnlyExample'
    Message(const T& data) {
    ^
main.cpp:29:24: note: in instantiation of member function 'Message<MoveOnlyExample>::Message' requested here
        segment_ = new Message<T>(d);
                       ^
main.cpp:51:11: note: in instantiation of member function 'Store<MoveOnlyExample>::Add' requested here
    store.Add(std::move(m));
          ^
main.cpp:36:5: note: 'MoveOnlyExample' has been explicitly marked deleted here
    MoveOnlyExample() = delete;
    ^
main.cpp:9:20: error: overload resolution selected deleted operator '='
        this->data = data;
        ~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~
main.cpp:42:22: note: candidate function has been explicitly deleted
    MoveOnlyExample& operator=(const MoveOnlyExample&) = delete;
                     ^
main.cpp:41:22: note: candidate function not viable: 1st argument ('const MoveOnlyExample') would lose const qualifier
    MoveOnlyExample& operator=(MoveOnlyExample&&) = default;
                     ^
```

Why and how can I fix them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the error is caused at the compilation of the class `Message<MoveOnlyExample>`. When you write:

```
T data;
...
Message(T&& data) {
    this->data = std::move(data);
}
```

The compiler has to first default construct the data member and only then use the move assignment. If you want to use a move constructor, you must use the initialization idiom:

```
T data;
...
Message(T&& data): data(std::move(data)) {}
```

Here the `data` member is indeed move constructed.

But this is not all. As said by @SebastianHoffmann you have to repeat `std::move` on each and every place

```
void Add(T&& d) {
    segment_ = new Message<T>(std::move(d));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the `Add()` method:

```
void Add(T&& d) {
    segment_ = new Message<T>(d);
}
```

**Move-semantic don't propagate!** As far as the compiler is concerned, `d` is a lvalue and as such `new Message<T>(d)` calls the copy-constructor.

You'll have to explicitely tell the compiler that you want to move from `d` again, i.e:

```
void Add(T&& d) {
    segment_ = new Message<T>(std::move(d));
}
```